# why mongodb doesnt connect with my nodejs simple application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect mongodb to my express nodejs web application. I am fresh new to nodejs. I am following this tutorial video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eB9Fq9I5ocs but I couldn't complete it due to the connection of mongodb.

the app.js code I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');



Genre = require('./models/genre');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');


mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
console.error('mongodb connection error', err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
console.info(`Connected to mongodb`);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => {
console.info('Disconnected from mongodb');
});
// var mongoose = connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');
// var db = mongoose.connection;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('api/genres', function(req , res){
Genre.getGenres(function(err, genres){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genres);
})
});

app.listen(3666);
console.log('Server Running On http://localhost:3666');
```

and this is the genre.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');


var genreSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:{
    type: String,
    requires: true
},
create_date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
 }
});

var Genre = module.exports = mongoose.model('Genre', genreSchema);

module.exports.getGenres = function(callback, limit){
Genre.find(callback).limit(limit);

}
```

and this is a picture of the database in the terminal

[image: Monogdb shall]

The Error that I got:
[image]

I know this is a basic question but I couldnt figured out I check on google there are others way to connect to the database but I need to know why this particular way which I just followed from the tutorial video havent worked.
As you noticed I am a new to nodejs web development so if you could suggest websites or youtube channels to get me start it I would appreciate it.

Comment: just use conn('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of undefined `connect` function you should use `mongoose.connect(...)`:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');
```

But this function is deprecated, you could silence the warning, setting `{ useMongoClient: true }` in options, but it's not recommended.

The best way is to use `mongoose.connection` object and its `openUri` method:

```
let conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.openUri('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');

conn.on('error', err => console.error('mongodb connection error', err));

conn.on('connected', () => console.info(`Connected to mongodb`));

conn.on('disconnected', () => console.info('Disconnected from mongodb'));
```

Comment: I couldn't write the error here I'll edit it in the question

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: what exactly works with no errors: mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/bookstore', {
  useMongoClient: true,
}); if you would to change your answer I would appreciate it to be reference for others. thanks

Comment: updated the answer again, using `mongoose.connection` is deprecated, you should use `mongoose.connection.openUri` instead.

Comment: I got this error ReferenceError: logger is not defined

Comment: Yes, it's my external logger, replaced it to `console`.

Comment: I got problem in getting the data from the database can you check the edited question again please

Comment: If you have another question, please revert current question to the previous version, and create a new one. Because currently this answer not relevant to the question.